# Not able to identify the objects inside the grid in RFT 8.6 version for flex application

Tags: rft

I am using RFT 8.6 version for testing flex application.In my application i am not able to identify the object inside the grid in which i would like to insert the data in the text fields can anybody help me out how to identify the inner objects of grid.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it's more understandable.

Comment: In my flex application, there is  grid(which RFT's test object is recognising through insert test object method) but there are some text fields inside this grid into which I want to insert the data but this field are not getting recognised by the object recognizer.

Comment: I meant edit the question not comment.